# Exporting gridview to microsoft powerpoint in c#

Tags: asp.net

I want to export gridview to powerpoint.I have the following code.But I have the following problems:

1. when I am using it for ms office 2010.its giving error:

   > Powerpoint cannot read c:\users\filename.ppt. The presentation cannot
   >   be opened. Your antivirus program may prevent you from opening the
   >   presentation. To fix this problem, make sure your antivirus program is
   >   current and working correctly. If the problem persists and the
   >   presentation is from someone that you trust, turn off your antivirus
   >   program, and then try to open the presentation again. If you do this,
   >   make sure you turn on your antivirus program again after you open the
   >   presentation.
2. when I am using it for ms office 2007,its opening but there is no gridview

CODE:

```
       Response.Clear();

       Response.Buffer = true;

       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.ppt");

       Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
       Response.Charset = ""; 
     //  this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-       officedocument.presentationml.presentation";

       this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12";

       this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";

    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ppt";

    GridView2.AllowPaging = false; 

    GridView2.DataBind();

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter(); 
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite); 
    GridView2.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

     Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

   Response.End();
   Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an external library to generate your ppt or pptx.
Like aspose.net or Open xml.

Comment: :Thanks for your time.But could you please explain your point-i mean how should I modify the above code or else.

Comment: please if you don't want to use an external library, refer to this page http://forums.asp.net/p/1123406/1763138.aspx#1763138

Comment: Hi GeorgesD,I already tried this code but its giving me the same problems above.I have already tried out ms word export successfully,but its seems to be a bit painful for powerpoint export.Pls help to solve the problem.Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: please try with aspose and have a look at that thread http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/98958/export-gridview-table-data-to-powerpoint-asp.net.aspx

Comment: Maybe you can't do it directly think of another way to do it. Generate an image from your gridview and after create you powerpoint, something like that...